# How do you delete an edge?

Tags: jaseci

I want to delete the edge that connects two nodes. How do I do that?

node1 -[link]-> node2 ;
I want to delete this link .

Answer (score 1):

To delete an edge between existing nodes use this syntax `node1 !-[link]-> node2 ;`